# Endpoints method not working, why?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, http-status-code-503

When I test my google endpoints API in the api explorer, the saveProfile method throws the `503 Service Unavailable` error, but all other methods work fine.

Here is the **saveProfile** method in my endpoint:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "saveProfile")
public Profile saveProfile(final ProfileForm profileForm) {
    String firstName = profileForm.getFirstName();
    String lastName = profileForm.getLastName();
    String email = profileForm.getEmail();

    Profile profile = new Profile("124234132", email, firstName, lastName);

    ofy().save().entity(profile).now();

    return profile;
}
```

Here is the **Profile entity** class:

```
@Entity
public class Profile {

    @Id
    private String userId;

    private String email;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    public Profile(String userId, String email, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.email = email;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

Here is the **profileForm** class:

```
public class ProfileForm {

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String email;

    public ProfileForm() {}

    public ProfileForm(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
}
```

I have registered the entity and have set the `API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID` as well as the web and android client IDs.

Does somebody understand how to fix this so that the method just returns the profile object as it should?

Comment: Documentation says that, *"All HTTP 5xx status codes are converted to be HTTP 503 in the client response."* https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/exceptions#exceptions_provided_by_endpoints

Comment: You should find information about the error happening under the hood in the request logs in your [console](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs_viewer).

Comment: user2004685, so how do I get it to return a success code (i think 200 means success).

Comment: zapl, this is one of the things it says: JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class com.example.tomfinet.myapplication.backend.model.Profile and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for Profile to be serializable you need to define getters and setters for each of its fields (ex. getUserId(), setUserId(string Id)).

An Objectify entity must also include a no-arg constructor: https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Entities

Let me know if that fixes the error.

Comment: Even for the field annotated with @Id ?